# Get specific part of url of a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I want to get a specific part of a url between the third and fourth slashes of a link on the page.

EDIT: Sorry I don't think I was clear the first time, I meant getting the specific part of the url OF A LINK found on the page.

Comment: How can we help you with this? Have you tried to tackle this problem?

Comment: Are you *sure*? Bearing in mind that there are two consecutive slashes at the beginning of an absolute URL? Given the link '`http://www.example.com/directory1/directory2/directory3/directory4/index.html`' what would you expect to get from 'between the third and fourth slashes'?

Comment: @Blender I already searched around but only found codes for getting specific parts of the url of the page you're on, not the link found on the page you're on.

Comment: you should elaborate you question and should specify which is your domain, that means on what purpose you are asking that question ??

Comment: @David Thomas Ignoring the http:// slashes, I want to get the directory3 text

Answer (score 7):

```
var getSegment = function (url, index) {
   return url.replace(/^https?:\/\//, '').split('/')[index];
}
```

Usage:

```
getSegment("http://domain.com/a/b/c/d/e", 4); // "d"
```

---

The `replace` makes sure that the first two slashes after the protocol (`http` or `https`) don't count.

Comment: OP is asking for a part of the path of a url found on the page, not the current url.

Comment: Removed downvote. Note also though that if the url has a querystring or anchor, that will be included with the last segment.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/b6dd6/) a working example of getting a particular path segment.

Code:

```
var url = "www.test.com/one/two/three?p1=v&p2=v#anc";
var file = url.split('?')[0];
var pathanddomain = file.split('/');
var path = pathanddomain.splice(1, pathanddomain.length-1);
var pathIndexToGet = 2;
document.write(path[pathIndexToGet]);​
```

If you want to do this for the current page, use:

```
var url = window.location.href;
```

Also, if your url starts with http(s)://, you will need to remove this.

Comment: The url will constantly change, is it possible I can change the first line to something like:         var url = "www.test.com/one/two/*?p1=v&p2=v#anc";

Comment: @user1560022. You can change the first line to anything you like. It can be a variable, it can be hard coded (as the example), it can be pulled from the browser, or it can be produced by a function call.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to achieve with the asterisk but if that's the url you have then yes, this code will work. I should warn you though, * is not a valid url character and you should avoid using it without it being [url encoded](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

Comment: Well as I said, the url will constantly change so hardcoding the url in this code will mean that I will have to change the code too. The asterisk means that anything could be there.

Comment: @user1560022. That's fine. It doesn't matter how deep the path is, the code will continue to work. The `.split('/')` returns an array of the path segments. You simply supply it with the index you require. `.split('/')[2]`, `.split('/')[25]` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
var link = 'http://www.example.com/directory1/directory2/directory3/directory4/index.html';

console.log(link.split('/')[5]);​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Eubmg/).

The reason we're using `[5]` not `[4]` is because of the two slashes at the beginning of the URL, and because JavaScript arrays are zero-based.

Answer (score 0):

you should elaborate you question and should specify which is your domain, that means on what purpose you are asking that question ??

This  may help you:

```
var urlValue = url.split("/");
```

Then store urlValue as array.
then pick up third and forth value of the urlvalue on array.

Comment: Voting down because this needs more details or an example.